# How to run System Command in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, command, system

I am developing one web application in javaScript/JQuery where i need to run system command on client and server both side. How can it be done?

Regards

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can't run shell commands on the client via the browser.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy in IE you can.. not straight forwards thought//

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because that would be a big security issue.

If you need this to be done you can either ask your client to run it, or let them download a file that will do it for them. Other options are ActiveX/Java applet and so on...

Comment: Ok, how can i run on server side?

Comment: This is where you need to be more precise about "run system command". Open a file? Execute something? What do you need to do exactly?

Comment: And of course, what web server are you running? Programming language?

Comment: I am using JavaScript as programming language and Apache as web server. I need to execute command (basically need to run some C++ exe files).

Comment: Still not enough info. What programming language do you run on the server?

Comment: Basically i am using PHP but i need to call function from HighChart (JavaScript) on click event so JavaScript is the one who need to execute the commands.

Comment: JavaScript can't execute command on your php server.
It can send a request to it, and in that request you can do what you need in php.

Since you tagged the question as javascript-related and not php, and I don't know php, I suggest you open a new question (or better- search) how to execute a file with php.

Comment: How javascript can send a request to Php other programming language.

Comment: This is not for this discussion, do some research.